# How to refresh view in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, image, ipad, uiimageview

I wanted to create a gallery. It loads different images based on the category, that a user selects. I used to populate images in UIImageViews.

My when selecting different categories is that it does not clear the previously selected images. This is my code for populating images.

```
-(void)refresh{

   categoryLabel.text = treatment.treatmentName;
   NSMutableArray  *galleryImages =[NSMutableArray alloc] ;
   galleryImages = [[PatientImage alloc]find:treatment.treatmentId];

   int imgCount = [galleryImages count];

    for(int i=0;i<imgCount;i++){

        PatientImage *apatientImage = [galleryImages objectAtIndex:i]; 

        UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:apatientImage.imageBefore]; 
        UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img1];
        myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTopRight;
        myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(120+i*240,120.0,100.0, 100.0);
       [self.view addSubview:myImageView];

        UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:apatientImage.imageAfter]; 
        UIImageView *myImageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img2];
        myImageView2.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTopRight;
        myImageView2.frame = CGRectMake(120+i*240+300,120.0,100.0, 100.0);
        [self.view addSubview:myImageView2];
    }
}
```

Comment: Without answering your question, let me do a little code-review :-) : `[[PatientImage alloc]find:treatment.treatmentId];` looks quite strange to me. Does  your find method initialize an object? Better coding style would be to have a `Patient` object which has an image property: `UIImage *patientImage = [[Patient alloc]initWithTreatmentId:treatment.treatmentId].patientImage`. Also `alloc` and `init*` should always go together. Alternatively you can get autoreleased objects like this: `[NSMutableArray array]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, You have some memory leaks there. You are allocating UIImageViews but are not releasing them anywhere, after you have added them to your view. I don't know if that applies to ARC, though. Same applies to your Mutable array, but I suppose you are releasing it after the 'for' loop somewhere, since it seems you posted code after omitting some of it.

As far as your actual question is concerned, I wouldn't do this this way. I would make the mutable array an object variable, and then fill it with my image views. When calling refresh again, I would first call -removeFromSuperview on each image view, then empty the array, then repopulate it and add the new subviews to my view. That is the simple way.

I don't know if you are using ARC, but you should be careful about memory management when using dynamically loaded views. Each time you add a view to another one, you increase its retain counter. You must then call release to remove ownership, and let the iOS runtime handle the rest.

Also note that operations such as this using views are expensive in terms of memory. So, another way of repopulating the gallery view is to just change the image an imageView holds. That will save you some memory, and time. In case the view doesn't have a constant number of images to be displayed, you can refine your algorithm to change the images on the already created image views, and then add more image views if necessary or delete the remaining ones, if any.

I hope I helped.

Comment: Im new for objective-c.There can be lot of mistakes. I appreciate  your valuable ideas.

Comment: Since you are new, and this is a season of change for iOS memory management (or at least, the front-end), I think you should first read about ARC (Automatic Reference Counting). I know you may be eager to continue with your project, but at least you should make sure that you know if your project uses ARC or not. Mentioning this information alone can save you much time when receiving replies from members in the forums, because you may encounter later problems that have roots in memory management. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

try at the start of refresh call

```
    [[self subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

or

```
    for (id imageView in self.subviews){
            if([imageView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) [imageView removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Comment: Would it not be better to change the images instead of removing the UIImages and then adding them again?

Comment: The first method will remove ALL subviews from the current view, which may be not what you want, if you have more subviews (like scroll views and buttons) than UIImageViews. The second one adds a little clarity, and is far better, but I still prefer an NSMutableArray as an object variable that holds the UIImageViews to be removed.

Comment: Could you post an edited code for this purpose @ChristosSotiriou,

Comment: Assuming that imageViews is an object property of type NSMutableArray that is already initialized before: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2155

Answer (score 1):

```
call [tableview reloadData] if You are using tableview to show your gallery images 
or call view's 
[self.view setNeedsDisplay] method for refreshing the view.
```

Comment: I have put setNeedsDisplay code in the begining of the refresh function. But it didnt work. I dont know is that the write place for it. Thanks.

Comment: setNeedsDisplay is not going to work. setNeedsDisplay is for UIView specific operations. If you had a custom view subclass in which you had overridden -drawRect, then calling setNeedsDisplay would refresh the view according to -drawRect. What you describe, however, is not the case. Use the refresh function to deallocate the previews views and allocate new ones.